# Retrieve Lotus Notes contact information using contact ID in c#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

Im developing a tool that needs to access to the names.nsf database inside IBM Lotus Notes, and, using the lotus contact ID (Employee ID) (this id will be provided by the user), retrieve the full information of the person (Name, Position, Phone #....)

I found an example at Codeproject.com (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18517/Lotus-Notes-Integration-with-Microsoft-NET-Platfor), however it takes around 10 minutes to get the information the way the example does it (the database has more or less 5000 entries), so I'm searching for a faster way of doing it (if I actually use Lotus notes for this it takes about a second!).

Is there a way to accomplish this task without having the user waiting for minutes?

Thought that maybe you can help me out with this one.

Comment: Have you tried a second time? It sounds like the view was not indexed in names.nsf.

Comment: Yes, I tried quite a few times. Same result.

Comment: The sample code that you pointed to is using a local names.nsf database.  Are you doing that? Or are you accessing the names.nsf database on a Domino server?

Comment: Slightly off-topic suggestion, but why not use LDAP to query the Domino Directory?

Comment: I'm accessing on a Domino sever. The example has the option to fetch from server, right?

Comment: @booyaa, I think that the Lotus Server has LDAP disabled (tried to connect using LDAP, server down or not reachable)

Comment: @mradzinski006 ask your notes admin to activate it. usually this involves a server configuration change and loading the actual ldap server task.

Answer (score 1):

The sample you are using goes through the view using

```
NotesViewEntry viewEntry = notesViewCollection.GetNthEntry( rowCount );
```

This is (one of) the worst methods to use as it goes for every iteration from the top of the view and iterates through all docs until it reached the nth document.

There are two options: 
1) Optimize this code by using

```
NotesViewEntry viewEntry = notesViewCollection.GetFirstEntry();
```

and at the end

```
viewEntry = notesViewCollection.GetNextEntry(viewEntry);
```

2) (in my humble opinion the better way): Change the code:
- you need a view with the first column sorted by your key => contact ID (Employee ID) 
- You can the access the ViewEntry by a code like

```
LotusNotesView.GetEntryByKey( EmployeeID, true);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please be more specific? I'm not getting the part when you say that I need a view with the first column sorted by the EmployeeID key. Thanks for the help, seriously appreciate it

Comment: He's saying you should ask your Domino administrators to add a custom view to Names.nsf for you.  Most administrators, however, will refuse this request but yours might allow it.  If they allow it, then you want a view with selection formula Type="Person", and the formula for the first column will simply be EmployeeId and the sorting property for that column will be enabled.  That will allow you to use the getDocumentByKey() method, passing in the employee id info that your user provided.

Comment: Yeah, I asked them... needless to say they sent me an e-mail with a big NO, hehehe. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky the *names.nsf* is full text indexed. If it's not you could try to ask if it could be full text indexed. When it's indexed you can get the person document quicly like this:

```
LotusNotesView.FTSearch("[EmployeeID]=1234567", 1);
NotesDocument docPerson = LotusNotesView.GetFirstDocument();
```

Comment: FTSearch does not expose the GetFirstDocument method :(

Comment: @mradzinski006 You are right, sorry about that! I have corrected the code in the answer.

Comment: I've corrected the correction ;-)  The FTSearch result needs to be assigned to a NotesDocumentCollection object.  Also, I added a check of the Count before calling getFirstDocument.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I reverted it back. NotesView.FTSearch returns a Long data type (number of matches found) and "filters the view so it represents only those documents that match the full-text query". My original code would have been correct if NotesView.FTSearch returned NotesDocumentCollection.

Comment: Ah.  I forgot about the NotesView version of the FTSearch method.  And good choice, because that has the extra benefit of only including docs that fit the current view's selection formula, so it won't get false hits if someone writes an agent that adds an EmployeeID field to non-person docs.

Answer (score 0):

The use of GetNthEntry certainly causes some performance issues.  I've taken the relevant code from that site and rewrote it to use the GetFirst/GetNext pattern, which is recommended for all view processing in Lotus Notes.

Note this hasn't been tested, of course.  The point is to get the first entry in your collection, check that it is an object, and then process it.  At the end of the loop, get the next entry and repeat until you hit null.

```
    NotesViewEntryCollection  notesViewCollection = LotusNotesView.AllEntries;
    NotesViewEntry viewEntry = notesViewCollection.GetFirstEntry();

    while (viewEntry != null)
    {
        //Get the first document of particular entry.
        NotesDocument document =  viewEntry.Document;

        object documentItems = document.Items;
        Array itemArray1 = (System.Array)documentItems;

        for( int itemCount=0 ; itemCount< itemArray1.Length; itemCount++ )
        {
            NotesItem notesItem = 
            (Domino.NotesItem)itemArray1.GetValue( itemCount );

            //compare field value with specific value entered by user
            if( notesItem.Text !=null )
            {
                if( (notesItem.Text.ToUpper()).StartsWith( fieldValue ))
                {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    for( int icount=0 ; icount< itemArray1.Length; icount++ )
                    {
                        NotesItem searchedNotesItem =
            (Domino.NotesItem)itemArray1.GetValue( icount );
                        string FieldName = searchedNotesItem.Name.ToString();
                        //For FirstName
                        if( searchedNotesItem.Name == "FirstName" )
                            contact.FirstName= searchedNotesItem.Text;

                        //For LastName
                        if( searchedNotesItem.Name == "LastName" )
                            contact.LastName = searchedNotesItem.Text;
                        //For Office Phone Number
                        if( searchedNotesItem.Name == "OfficePhoneNumber" )
                            contact.OfficePhoneNumber = searchedNotesItem.Text;

                        if( searchedNotesItem.Name  == "InternetAddress" )
                            contact.EmailId = searchedNotesItem.Text;

                    }//end for
                    contactsList.Add( contact );
                    break;
                }//End if
            }
        }

        //Get the nth entry of the selected view according to the iteration.
        NotesViewEntry viewEntry = notesViewCollection.GetNextEntry(viewEntry);        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried the code you posted, but its still veeeery slow, in fact, took almost the same time as the one posted at Codeproject. Thank you very much again!

Comment: The above code will be faster than using getNthDocument, but it's still going to be slow because on average it has to open 50% of the documents in your names.nsf database to find the one you are looking for.  10 minutes, however, is extreme.  Something besides your algorithm seems to be slowing you down.

Comment: Yeah, its taking if not 10, 7 minutes. I'm researching with the network team to discard a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking the user to provide his Employee ID?  You should ask him to provide his Notes username (either FullName or ShortName), or his email address.  Any of those can be looked up very quickly in the $Users view in names.nsf, giving you fast access to the document containing all the data that you need.

Note: I'm aware that some companies actually enter their Employee ID into the ShortName field in names.nsf.  If that's the case for your organization, then what you should be doing is opening a `NotesView` object using the `NotesDatabase.getView()` method, and then use the NotesView.getDocumentByKey() method to get the document for the user.  E.g., something like this:

```
NotesView usersView = namesDb.getView("$Users");
NotesDocument userDoc = usersView.getDocumentByKey(employeeId);
```

Then just read the data that you want, using userDoc.getItemValue() for each information field that you are interested in.  You should only do a loop through the entire userdoc.Items array if you are really trying to capture everything, including a bunch of internal-use values.

Comment: I tried your method using full names and it works perfectly, however it's not working when using the Employee Id... I will keep researching further because this method proved to be extremely fast.

Comment: It will only work for EmployeeID if the users have previously entered the EmployeeID in the shortname field in names.nsf.  If this is not your company's standard practice, then the earlier suggestion of adding a view that is indexed by EmployeeID is the only way you will get the same level of speed.  But since most Domino administrators will not allow adding views to names.nsf, again I strongly suggest you change your requirements! Just the employees enter their Full Name or their Email Address instead of Employee ID.   That will be fast, and you can retrieve the EmployeeId from the document.